# Prevent Command Injection of piped commands

Tags: ruby, bash

I need to run a piped bash command in my ruby script.

Therefor I need to pass arguments to the bash command and escape them to prevent command injections. This question is not about the bash commands itself, so I'll try to simplify it.

bash command: `command1 arg1 | command2 arg2`

If i run this command within the system method, I get my expected result, but the arguments won't be escaped.

`system("command1 #{arg1} | command2 #{arg2}")`

If I pass multiple strings to the system method, the first string will act as command, the others will be added as arguments. This is a popular way of  preventing command injections in ruby.

`system('command1', arg1, '| command2', arg2)`

My Problem is, that I lose the ability to pipe bash commands if I need to escape them. (In this case, command2 will act as argument as well.)

Does anybody have a solution for that?

**Update:**

```
std_out = Open3.capture2('command1', arg1)[0]
result  = Open3.capture2('command2', arg2, stdin_data: std_out)[0]
```

Open3 offers several ways of defining stdin and stdout.

Comment: In Python, one would create two separate `Popen` instances and connect the output of the first to the input of the second, without using the shell at all. (`p1 = Popen(["command1", arg1], stdout=PIPE); call(["command2", arg2], stdin=p1.stdout)`). I presume Ruby has something similar? (Possibly `pipeline_rw`, or something else in `Open3`?)

Comment: Thanks!
Open3.capture2('cmd', arg, stdin_data: data) worked for med.